# TV show about a group of people that travel through time to the past trying to identify an evil character

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

I barely remember a TV show I saw as a kid (mid-late 1970's or early 1980's). I've tried to search but I can't find. It was in Spanish TV (TVE) but I'm sure that was not produced in Spain.

It was about a group of people that travel through time to the past trying to identify an evil character mingled with other people of the time. The crew had to identify what person is evil and do something (I don't remember what they had to do). At the end of the episode, when they are going to capture this evil person, this person escape to another time.

Comment: Was there a blue British police box involved?

Comment: http://www.lara.on.ca/~boxall/All-TTseries2016f.htm might include this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [Into The Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Labyrinth_(TV_series)) which was on UK television in the early 1980's.
A wizard called Rothgo gets a group of three children to travel through time looking for an atrefact called the Nidus, while they are opposed by the witch Belor.

I vaguely remember each episode ending with the children about to get hold of the Nidus, when Belor would shout "I deny you the Nidus!" and it was transported to a different time.