Wizard trapped in a cave, and some kids travel to the past find an item that could free him
This is a show from 70's-early 80's. It was about a wizard trapped in a cave and some kids that travel to the past and try to find an item that could free him.
I believe it was on PBS, but that was a long time ago and I'm not sure now.

Hello,I'm new here. I finally got the answer! Thank you to whomever found it for me.  I really appreciate it.

If it was Into the Labyrinth, don't forget to click the green tick to mark this one as solved! If it wasn't, could you post an answer to tell us all what it was?

Could this be Into the Labyrinth? This was a British children's TV series, first broadcast in 1980.
It deals with a wizard, Rothgo, who was weakened and left trapped in a cavern after a battle with his nemesis Belor. Three children from the present day try to assist him by recovering a magical amulet called the Nidus. As the wikipedia summary describes:

Rothgo sends the children through different periods of time to search
for the Nidus, which is disguised as a different object in each time
period and can only be seen in reflection. The children arrive in
various settings in history or ancient mythology (the French
Revolution, Ancient Greece, English Civil War, etc.), in which they
find an earlier version of Rothgo himself, playing a character from
each period. Together they search for the Nidus, but their attempts
are constantly thwarted by Belor who also appears in each time period,
disguised as a character herself.


If it is Into The Labyrinth, then this might be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229889/tv-show-about-a-group-of-people-that-travel-through-time-to-the-past-trying-to-i/229893#229893
